is there a way to force minutes vs. months format
I'm working in excel and would like to create a column of sequential minutes based on a given datetime.  The line currently reads:
=@daytime+(ROW()-ROW(INDEX(A$1:A1; 1)))/1440

This gives a nice readout of minutes that I can click+drag out along a column and is compatible with use in a table. (Perhaps there's already a better way to do this, but after trying a few things this worked.)
I can easily format this as hh:mm, but when I try for the goal format of :mm it automatically assumes I mean months, not minutes.  I can think of some workarounds (switching to text, converting to seconds for which there is no possible confusion, etc.) but I'm wondering if it's possible to force the minutes format somehow without involving hours or seconds.

Use the following format: [mm]
(the brackets allow you to format time as a duration and not a time of day)

To use the same in a formula; =TEXT(A1,"[mm]")

thanks! I think this is the best option since I can keep the data in datetime format and use it without unwrapping.

If this answer works for you then consider marking it as correct (see the checkmark next to it)

Wrap your formula with MINUTE() and then use a custom format of 00
